# Will my app work on a device with API7 if I compile for API24 and use the support library v7?

Tags: android, android-support-library

How can I tell/predict - without testing - what features will work/not work on a device with API-7 if an app is developed and tested on a device with API 24 (using the support library v7)?

Comment: This is a relevant blogpost : http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/06/android-support-library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest support libraries **v.24.2.0**  removed support for Android 2.2 (API level 8) and lower.
Now you have this new `minSdk`

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9" />.
```

Then if you want to work with minSdk=7 you have to use the 24.1.1 but you will not able to update the libraries in the future.

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

Comment: Thanks ! If I am using Java8 features, then will it still work for  > API 8 ?